# SSIS returns Null when query works

Tags: ssis, null, case

```
CASE WHEN o.ORDER_TYPE_ID = '0-JFE3' OR 
(o.ORDER_TYPE_ID = '1-55T3' AND 
po.ORDER_TYPE_ID = '0-JFE3') Then 'Y'
    Else 'N'
    End as Extranet_Order
```

Above is the code that returns `Y` and `N` in preview but the value becomes  `Null` in `DT_STR` to `CHAR(1) null` column.

Can you see what's wrong?

Comment: Please add some more context.

Comment: this case statement returns Y and N in TSQL but in my SSIS package it is only returning NULL the data type in SSIS is String(DT_STR)  the destination column is CHAR(1)

Comment: When does the column become `null`? After executing the SELECT query or after inserting in the result table? You can debug your package and view the data flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/troubleshooting/debugging-data-flow

Comment: Thanks it is correct Y and N in the data viewer

Comment: Are you sure you are mapping the correct column?

Answer (score 0):

A stored procedure was altering the response there was nothing wrong with the query or SSIS but I want to thank rollstuhlfahrer for the debug tip above